# Login with Instagram in flutter 2.0

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth, instagram-api

I'm trying to implement Instagram login with my flutter app by following the below approach. https://medium.com/hackernoon/instagram-authentication-with-flutter-df6424d2d56c

They are using http://localhost:8585 as redirect URI. But it's not supporting HTTP in the valid o auth redirect URI in developer account settings. Is there any other approach to continue with Instagram login in flutter? If I use any HTTPS redirect uris, the web view is not getting closed.

Comment: I ended up creating my backend on a server to handle redirects.

Answer (score 2):

The example you linked sets up a local web server to handle redirects and then uses 'http://localhost:XXXX' to listen to redirects. This stopped working when Instagram begin to require HTTPS.

A different approach is to intercept the navigation from the WebView in the first place.

1. Make sure you use `webview_flutter` package instead of `flutter_webview_plugin` used in that example.
2. In Instagram auth settings, type any redirect URI like `https://yourdomain.com`. It does not matter since the redirect will be intercepted.
3. Somewhere in your screen create this webview widget:

```
static const _redirectUrl = 'https://yourdomain.com';
static const _authUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=$_redirectUrl&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code';

// ...

WebView(
  initialUrl: _authUrl,
  navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
    // This can intercept any navigation within the WebView.
    if(request.url.startsWith(_redirectUrl)){
      final startIndex = request.url.indexOf('code=');
      final endIndex = request.url.lastIndexOf('#');
      final code = request.url.substring(startIndex + 5, endIndex);
      _logIn(code);
      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
    }
    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
  },
),

// ...

void _logIn(String code) {
  // Continue as in your example.
}
```

Credit:

I used the code in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83RzY78Lg-E

And its GitHub: https://github.com/loydkim/sign_up_instagram/blob/master/lib/main.dart